# Javascript numerical calculation concerns

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a currency converter with javascript, e.g., convert USD to SGD. Do you know any article or trick about concerns like precision issue that I need to tackle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accuracy seems to be the biggest issue here. There are many good sources to be found around the internet.
[This short article by William Bontragerone handles the accuracy problem sufficently.](http://www.web-source.net/web_development/currency_formatting.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Just retain precision until you have to display the results on the page.  And always prepare for the possibility that the user could put anything as input, including telephone numbers.